# ReactJs Formik with bootstrap select facing problem to set object

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set select item as object in Formik field . when i select a item from select dropdown which is develop with formik and bootstrap select i am trying to set field data as full object but it making it String value like

```
value: "[object Object]"
```

here is the code :

```
const renderValue = (fieldName, event) => {
      setFieldValue(fieldName, event.target.value);
    };
    return (
      <select 
        {...field}
        onChange={event => renderValue(field.name, event)} 
        {...other}>
        {options && options.length ?
          options.map((item, index) =>
            <option value={item}>{item.name}</option>) 
          : null}
      </select>
    );
```

is there any way to set value as Object  !

Comment: Can you add your code to codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-architecture-1nvr0

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cannon-1mj8u here is the working link

Comment: nope its converting to string value ("{"id":2,"name":"USA"}")  i need to set as object { id: 2, name: "USA" }

Comment: while setting the value parse it, something like `JSON.parse(event.target.value)`

Comment: yea nice suggestion but i need to set as object

Comment: when you parse it you'll get an object right?

Comment: i can convert it to json but look field value is set as string object. my requirement is to set value as object not string object !

Comment: ahhhhh got solutions

Comment: here is the solutions https://codesandbox.io/s/new-architecture-1nvr0